# Django Make a Left Join with new col or empity field

Tags: django, many-to-many

i need print all items but also i need know if current user `request.user` have that item in list
with SQL is just something like

```
select * from item as i
Left JOIN UserItems as ui ON ui.item=i.id
left Join user as u ON ui.user=u.id
```

so i just need check if u.id is not null, how i have to do with django for get all item list?

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class UserItems(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250 )
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

obviously `UserItems.objects.filter(useritem__user=request.user)` dosen't get all items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate with an [**`Exists`** subquery [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Item.objects.annotate(
    user_added=Exists(
        UserItems.objects.filter(item_id=OuterRef('pk'), user=request.user)
    )
)
```

The `Item`s that arise from this will have an extra attribute `user_added` that is `True` if there exists a `UserItems` for the `request.user` and that `Item` and `False` otherwise.